# CountVectorizer() in scikit-learn Python gives Memory error when feeding big Dataset. Same code with Smaller dataset works fine, what am I missing?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I am Working on Two Class Machine Learning Problem. Training Set contains 2-Millions Rows of URL(Strings) and Label 0 and 1. Classifier LogisticRegression() should predict any of two labels when testing datasets are passed. **I am getting 95% accuracy results when i use smaller dataset i.e 78,000 URL and 0 and 1 as labels.**

The Problem I am having is When I feed in big dataset (2 million row of URL strings) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile

execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:/Users/Slim/.xy/startups/start/chi2-94.85 - Copy.py", line 48, in <module>

bi_counts = bi.fit_transform(url_list)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 780, in fit_transform

vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 717, in _count_vocab

j_indices.append(vocabulary[feature])
MemoryError
```

My code which is working for small datasets with fair enough accuracy is

```
bi = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3, 3),binary = True, max_features=9000, analyzer='char_wb')
bi_counts = bi.fit_transform(url_list)
tf = TfidfTransformer(norm='l2')
X_train_tf =tf.fit_transform(use_idf=True, bi_counts)
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1',intercept_scaling=0.5,random_state=True)
clf.fit(train_x2,y)
```

I tried to keep 'max_features' as minimum as possible say max_features=100, but still same result.

**Please Note:**

- I am Using core i5 with 4GB ram
- I tried the same code on 8GB ram but
  no luck
- I am using Pyhon 2.7.6 with sklearn, NumPy 1.8.1, SciPy 0.14.0, Matplotlib 1.3.1

**UPDATE:**

@Andreas Mueller suggested to used HashingVectorizer(), i used it with small and large datasets, 78,000 dataset compiled successfully but 2-million dataset gave me same memory error as shown above. I tried it on 8GB ram and in-use memory space = 30% when compiling big dataset.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more it seems slightly odd. You are using ``char_wb`` with 3-grams, so there shouldn't be that many features, right? How many features did you get for the smaller data set?

Comment: with only 3-gram i am getting 40968 features and 54% accuracy. With only char_wb i am getting only 50 features from 78,000 URLs, dataset has one URL per row. while applying char_wb and 3-gram i am getting 25,376 features and 95% accuracy.

Comment: Ok 25k seems reasonable for char 3-grams.

Comment: @Andreas Mueller, i get 25k features with 3-gram and char_wb when both use combine. with only 3-gram in use i get 40k features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC the max_features is only applied after the whole dictionary is computed.
The easiest way out is to use the `HashingVectorizer` that does not compute a dictionary.
You will lose the ability to get the corresponding token for a feature, but you shouldn't run into memory issues any more.

Comment: Tried HashingVectorizer before, But now i checked it again on same small data set of 78,000 rows and it worked, but when i load in my main dataset 2-millions rows, console showed same memory error. In traceback call error originate start from HashingVectorizer transform phase.

Comment: Then I guess the result is to large for your RAM. You can use out of core methods: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/scaling_strategies.html#scaling-with-instances-using-out-of-core-learning this will not allow you to do the TFIDF scaling, though.

Comment: ok working on it... btw I am working in 32-bit python. Is this has something thing todo with my problem?

Comment: Oh, yeah that means you can only use 2gb of ram afaik.

Comment: In deed, this was 32 bit problem, got results on 64bit python.thanks